# Not able to rerun failed TestSuites/Testcases created dynamically in robotframework

Tags: python, robotframework

I have created suite and testcases in suite dynamically . I want to rerun failed test cases using
pybot --rerunfailed C:\Users\GS-0815\PycharmProjects\Apex\out1.xml --output C:\Users\GS-0815\PycharmProjects\Apex\Failed\out1.xml "+suite.name
Result:

but it says sanity suite not found

PFA for test script (not able to attach rtf/txt file),How I can I provide suitepath which is created dynamically or else any other way

pasting code here.........

```
import os
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import *
from robot.api import TestSuite
from robot.api import ResultWriter
from robot.parsing.model import TestData
#from robot.output import TestSuite
from robot.running.context import EXECUTION_CONTEXTS

class TestRunner():
ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 2
ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'TEST SUITE'
def init(self):
print "in init"

def func(self,a):
    BuiltIn().log_to_console("in testrunner.py")
    self.ROBOT_LIBRARY_LISTENER = self

    #suite=EXECUTION_CONTEXTS.current.suite
    suite = TestSuite(name='Sanity',source=a)
    suite.configure()
    BuiltIn().log_to_console(suite)
    #BuiltIn().import_resource("C:/Users/GS-0815/PycharmProjects/Apex/demo.robot")
    print a

    suite.resource.imports.library('OperatingSystem')
    suite.resource.imports.library('C:/Users/GS-0815/PycharmProjects/Apex/keyw.py')
    #BuiltIn().import_resource('C:/Users/GS-0815/PycharmProjects/Apex/TestSuites/test.robot')
    suite.resource.imports.resource("C:/Users/GS-0815/PycharmProjects/Apex/TestSuites/test.robot")
    suite.keywords.create("t1",args=['in suite setup'],type="setup")


    test = suite.tests.create('WirelesswithSegmentation', tags=['smoke','abc'])
    test.keywords.create("abc", args=["hi","there","ddgdgd"])
    #test.keywords.create('Environment Variable Should Be Set', args=['SKYNET'])

    test = suite.tests.create('Test2', tags=['smoke'])
    #test.keywords.create('abc', args=['test2'],type='setup')
    test.keywords.create('Log to Console', args=['EXECUTION_CONTEXTS.current.suite'], type='setup')
    test.keywords.create('Log to Console', args=['&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&'])
    test.keywords.create('Log to Console', args=['test21'])


    test = suite.tests.create('Test3', tags=['xyz'])
    test.keywords.create('Log to Console', args=['hi there3'])






    suite2 = TestSuite('regression')
    suite2.resource.imports.library('OperatingSystem')
    #suite2.resource.imports.library('demo.robot')
    #suite.resource.imports.library('C:/Users/GS-0815/PycharmProjects/Apex/keyw.py')
    test = suite2.tests.create('WirelesswithSegmentation2', tags=['he','abc'])
    test.keywords.create('Log to Console', args=['hi there'])





    #suite.filter(included_tags=['xyz'])
    result =suite.run(output='out1.xml')
    result2=suite2.run(output='out2.xml')
    **os.system("pybot --rerunfailed C:\Users\GS-0815\PycharmProjects\Apex\out1.xml --output C:\Users\GS-0815\PycharmProjects\Apex\Failed\out1.xml "+suite.name**

     os.system('rebot -d C:\Users\GS-0815\PycharmProjects\Apex\TestSuites out1.xml out2.xml')


ob = TestRunner()
ob.func('C:\Users\GS-0815\PycharmProjects\Apex\TestSuites\suite1.robot')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made use of created output.xml to get list of failed suites along with Tcs and again passed those suites to suite.run() function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 options:

1. generate dynamic test cases with  ([--prerunmodifier](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#programmatic-modification-of-test-data))
2. export dynamically generated test suite to file and use it for rerun (but I cannot say how to do this - please search docs or ask another question)